# Import function that imports a json

Tags: python, import, path

I have the following data structure

- FolderA

  - A.py
  - data.json
- B.py

---

Inside B.py

```py
from FolderA.A import f

f()
```

Inside A.py

```py
def f():
   open("/FolderA/data.json", "r")
```

This results in Error:
 No such file or directory: "/FolderA/data.json"

---

Why is that?

Thank you :)

Comment: Is FolderA in your file system's root directory?

Comment: It is, e.g., C://Users/myName/Documents/FolderA.

Comment: Starting a path with a slash means that the path starts at your root directory. So `/FolderA/data.json` would mean ```C:\FolderA\data.json``` in your fs. If you lose the starting slash then `FolderA/data.json` would start from your current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @khelwood.

Replacing

```py
def f():
   open("/FolderA/data.json", "r")
```

by

```py
def f():
   open("FolderA/data.json", "r")
```

works fine.

Even though i could swear i tried this. Either way, its fine now.